# python dataframe doesn't make me add columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

'''   Hi guys I'm working with dataframes on python.
    I want to add at the end a new column called 'Third Level Description' and insert what is present in the column "Denomination of the supra-municipal Territorial Unit".
    When I run the script, however, it gives me a series of errors (I attach in the photo).
    If, on the other hand, I give him the position of the column, he gives me no error and does what I want.

the code is as follows:

```py
    colonne=list(df_elenco_comuni.columns.values)
    for i in colonne:
        print(i)

    print(len(colonne))


    #Inizio a mappare il file con  le varie colonne
    df_elenco_comuni['Country Code']=df_elenco_stati['Codice ISO 3166 alpha2']
    df_elenco_comuni['Country Description']=df_elenco_stati['Denominazione EN']
    df_elenco_comuni['First Level Code']=df_elenco_comuni['NUTS1']
    df_elenco_comuni['First Level Description']=df_elenco_comuni['Ripartizione geografica']
    df_elenco_comuni['Second Level Code']=df_elenco_comuni[colonne[22]]
    df_elenco_comuni['Second Level Description']=df_elenco_comuni['Denominazione regione']
    df_elenco_comuni['Third Level Code']=df_elenco_comuni['NUTS3']
    #df_elenco_comuni['Third Level Description']=df_elenco_comuni[colonne[2]]
    df_elenco_comuni['Third Level Description']=df_elenco_comuni["Denominazione dell'Unità territoriale sovracomunale"]
    df_elenco_comuni['Fourth Level Code']=df_elenco_comuni['Codice Comune formato alfanumerico']
    df_elenco_comuni['Fourth Level Description']=df_elenco_comuni['Denominazione in italiano']
    df_elenco_comuni['Fifth Level Code']=''
    df_elenco_comuni['Fifth Level Description']=''
    df_elenco_comuni['Population']=df_elenco_comuni['Popolazione legale 2011 (09/10/2011)']
    df_elenco_comuni['Size (kmq)']=''
    df_elenco_comuni['Start Date']=''
    df_elenco_comuni['End Date']=''
    df_elenco_comuni['Lat']=''
    df_elenco_comuni['Lon']=''
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome at SO! Please don't post the error messages as image, but copy and past the text in your question. That way future visitors to this thread can fully understand what your question even behind the image at the link might have vanished from the net. Also, others searching the web for this specific error might find a solution in this thread. This is not possible if the error messages are hidden in an image.

Comment: The error tells you that there is no such column ""Denominazione dell'Unità territoriale sovracomunale" in your dataframe. My first guess: Maybe that is a problem with the accent à in "Unità"? Inspect the dataframe with `df_elenco_comuni.columns` to see what's wrong with that column.

Comment: Anyway, instead of creating copies of the columns to change their names, you might want to have a look at `pandas.DataFrame.rename`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html